# WiFi keeps on disconnecting on hp probook 4430 on 16.04

Tags: wireless, hp

I tried some of solutions but didn't work out.

Output of  `lspci -knn` is below.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge 
[0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller 
[8086:0104] (rev 09) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller 
[103c:167e] 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller 
[0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
[8086:0116] (rev 09) DeviceName: 32 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: i915 Kernel modules: i915 00:16.0 Communication controller 
[0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 
[8086:1c3a] (rev 04) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: mei_me Kernel modules: mei_me 00:1a.0 USB controller 
[0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 
[8086:1c2d] (rev 04) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci 00:1b.0 Audio device 
[0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller 
[8086:1c20] (rev 04) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel 00:1c.0 PCI bridge 
[0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 
[8086:1c10] (rev b4) Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp 00:1c.1 PCI bridge 
[0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 
[8086:1c12] (rev b4) Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp 00:1c.2 PCI bridge 
[0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 
[8086:1c14] (rev b4) Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp 00:1c.3 PCI bridge 
[0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 
[8086:1c16] (rev b4) Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp 00:1c.5 PCI bridge 
[0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 
[8086:1c1a] (rev b4) Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel modules: shpchp 00:1d.0 USB controller 
[0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 
[8086:1c26] (rev 04) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci 00:1f.0 ISA bridge 
[0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller 
[8086:1c49] (rev 04) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich Kernel modules: lpc_ich 00:1f.2 SATA controller 
[0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller 
[8086:1c03] (rev 04) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: ahci Kernel modules: ahci 23:00.0 System peripheral 
[0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller 
[197b:2392] (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company SD/MMC Host Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci Kernel modules: sdhci_pci 23:00.2 SD Host controller 
[0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller 
[197b:2391] (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Standard SD Host Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel modules: sdhci_pci 23:00.3 System peripheral 
[0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller 
[197b:2393] (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MS Host Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: jmb38x_ms Kernel modules: jmb38x_ms 24:00.0 Network controller 
[0280]: Ralink corp. RT3592 Wireless 802.11abgn 2T/2R PCIe 
[1814:3592] DeviceName: WLAN Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RT3592 Wireless 802.11abgn 2T/2R PCIe 
[103c:1638] Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci Kernel modules: rt2800pci 25:00.0 Ethernet controller 
[0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
[10ec:8168] (rev 06) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
[103c:167e] Kernel driver in use: r8169 Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci -knn`.

Comment: anyone please help me